# RESTful - add subresource to a resource : POST /subresource or POST /resource/id/subresource?

Tags: rest

I want to add an attachment to a case.

Which request should I choose?

```
POST /cases/123/attachments
{
   "fileName" : "subscription.pdf",
   "content" : "JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjE1MzMgMCBvYmoNPDwvTGluZWF..."
}
```

or

```
POST /attachments
{
   "caseId" : 123,
   "fileName" : "subscription.pdf",
   "content" : "JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjE1MzMgMCBvYmoNPDwvTGluZWF..."
}
```

I guess both are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct. I would choose the second one, I don't like hierarchical URIs, since they get complicated by describing multi level hierarchies. I would use `GET /attachments/?case=id` to retrieve the attachments of a case.

Answer (score 4):

Both are fine though I'd go for the first one, since it makes the relation between cases and attachments more explicit. And then you can also retrieve all the attachments for a cases using `GET /cases/:id/attachments`

Answer (score 1):

If a single attachment can be shared amongst resources then the second one is correct. However, if an attachment is not independent of a case then the 1st one makes much better sense.

Can an attachment make sense without its case?